# trying to reach function inside a class javascript

Tags: javascript, function, class

Good evening, If someone could help me , I would be glad.I am trying to reach some functions in my Car class. Firstly I am trying to assign **inpSpeed** input value to Car class function Drive and then I wanna print out to console all cars info when I press the button: **btnRace** and the problem is I dont really know how to call them , because everytime I call them it says:"undefined".

here is my code so far:

```
carsArray = [];

btnCarName.onclick = function(){
    carsArray.push({/*obj.element1, obj.element2, obj.element3*/});
}

btnRace.onclick = function(){

    for(j in carsArray)
    {
        console.log(Car(carsArray[j]));
    }
}


function Car(name,speed)
{
  this.carBrand = name;
  this.speed = speed;
  this.distance = 0;

  this.Drive = function(time)
  {
        if(time > 0)
            return this.distance = (this.speed * (time/10));
  }

  this.printData = function()
  {
    for(var i = 0; i < Car.length; i++)
        {
            console.log('Car brand: ' + this.carBrand);
            console.log('Speed: ' + this.speed);
            console.log('distance: ' + this.Drive());
            console.log('---------------------------');
        }
  }
}
```

Comment: where are you defining carsArray?

Comment: `var car = new Car("example", 0); car.printData()`? However, you should drop that loop from the `printData` method, it only cares about the current instance not an array.

Comment: @Bergi so if I delete that one , do I need to specify the element I need like: car.printData(carsArray[j].name) ?

Comment: No, `printData` does take any arguments. If you are storing your `new Car(…)` instances in an array instead of the `car` variable as in my example, it would be `carsArray[i].printData();`

Comment: @Bergi now I get it , thanks , Bergi :)

Answer (score 0):

For the `this` keyword to work, you must instantiate `Car()` with the `new` keyword:

```
var toyota = new Car('toyota', 100)

console.log(toyota.speed);
```

There may however be a couple other issues. What exactly is expected from `Car.length`?

Comment: Car.lenght gives me just arrays lenght , because i use it to print all elements.

Comment: Are you trying to get the length of carsArray?

Comment: amm , in that place I should probably use carsArray.lenght instead , because I need to reach arrays elements , cause my class does not have any elements... I just realised.. or am I wrong ?     all that loop is incorrect itself , but my question would be then how to reach printData function to print all my arrays elements ?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to accomplish, but I think you probably should be checking `carsArray.length` since the length of the static `Cars` constructor function will likely not give you desired results - it would return the length of 1.

Comment: yeah , I wanna to just print all elements of carsArray